# Google PHP SDK not changing Accesstoken on setAccessToken

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-authentication, google-my-business-api

Im building a small Tool to manage multiple GMB Locations at once, but I run into a problem with the [google php api client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client).

I'm fetching accesstokens of multiple users/locations from my database and want to update them in a loop, but the google php api client does not change the used accesstokens in its requests on using [setAccesstoken](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/2d11de34a0dab8dcb872908f11e006c799b710f5/src/Google/Client.php#L422) for the second time.

Every run of the loop after the first will keep using the accesstoken from the first run, even though `getAccesstoken()` return the correct accesstoken. seems like the internally used `GuzzleClient` doesn't get updated to use the new token for the next requests.

Unfortunatly i couldn't find a method to force the sdk to update the `GuzzleClient` or recreate it. I hope you can help me out.

```
 foreach($this->getLocationsToUpdate() as $location){

    $oldAccessToken = $this->google->getClient()->getAccessToken();

    $placeData = $this->places->getFullPathAndToken($location);
    if($placeData !== null){

        try{
            //only sets the token correct on the first run.
            $this->google->setAccessToken($placeData['access_token']);

            $this->updateReviews($placeData);
            $this->updateQuestions($placeData);
            $this->updateMedia($placeData);

             // returns the correct token, but api requests in the methods above fail, since the auth header from the guzzle requests still use the token from the first run.
            var_dump($this->google->getClient()->getAccessToken());

            $this->google->setAccessToken($oldAccessToken);

        }catch(\Exception $e){                   
            $this->google->setAccessToken($oldAccessToken);
        }

    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
I made another example to remove all variables from my own code. Request 1 works fine, request 2 fails, because it still uses `$token1`, if i remove request 1, request 2 works fine.

```
<?php

define('BASE_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));

require_once BASE_DIR.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$token1 = '.....';
$token2 = '.....';

$name1 = 'accounts/115224257627719644685/locations/12065626487534884042';
$name2 = 'accounts/115299736292976731655/locations/295582818900206145';


$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(BASE_DIR.'/Config/Google/credentials.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://...../login/callback.html');
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setPrompt('consent');
$client->addScope(\Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL);
$client->addScope(\Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_PROFILE);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage");

// Request 1
$client->setAccessToken($token1);
$gmb = new \Google_Service_MyBusiness($client);
$media = $gmb->accounts_locations_media->listAccountsLocationsMedia($name1);
var_dump($media);

// Request 2 -- Fails because it still uses $token1
$client->setAccessToken($token2);
$gmb = new \Google_Service_MyBusiness($client);
$media = $gmb->accounts_locations_media->listAccountsLocationsMedia($name2);
var_dump($media);
```

Comment: It looks like (in the `getHttpClient()` method in the google client) the guzzle client is not recreated after changing the token, and I did not found any method which can force the client to reset it. I think the google client was not designed to use this way. Did you try creating a new instance of the google client for every user/token? It will be less elegant, but it will probably work..

Comment: creating new instances works fine, but creates unnecessary overhead i wanted to avoid, i'm coming from the facebook php sdk, which handles accesstoken changes like a breeze.

Comment: try calling the client `authorize` method after setting a new access token. I'm not entirely sure, but it looks like it is using the current access token. Like this:`$client->setAccessToken($token2); $client->authorize(null);`

Comment: `authorize()` gets its http client from `getHttpClient()` and `getHttpClient()` returns `$this->http` once its set, so unfortunately no way to regenerate the used http client via this way, setting a new accesstoken should just set `$this->http = null;` and everything would be fine and regenerated when needed again.

Comment: so this line in the authorize method does not do any difference right? `$http = $authHandler->attachToken($http, $token, (array) $scopes);`

Comment: i just anwsered my own question and opened an issue on github. thank you for your help @spielerds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug/not existing feature in the google php api client.

I reported an issue on github and hope to get clarity over there.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1672

EDIT:

I got a [reply](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1672#issuecomment-505032415) with a solution for my problem, over at Github. You need to manually clear the cache after setting a new accesstoken.

> Hi @Fredyy90,
>
> The client will cache access tokens for calls to the same service with
>   the same scopes. To change tokens, you can clear this cache:

```
$client->setAccessToken($token1); // <call 1>

$client->getCache()->clear();

$client->setAccessToken($token2); // <call 2>
```

> We'll see about ways we
>   can make this behavior clearer and provide more control to people
>   looking to modify the tokens.